# Как объединить запросы из цикла в один запрос, в postgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

Есть код, в цикле делаются запросы в базу. Как сделать с помощью union один запрос?

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $oldId = ExecSQL_SelectOne("SELECT point_ref FROM {$this->model->MainTable} WHERE id =".$id);
    ExecSQL_NoSelect("INSERT INTO history (id, c_type, employee_ref, object_name, object_ref, c_data, c_timestamp) VALUES (nextval
    ('history_id_seq'), 'upd', ".$_SESSION['emp_id'].",'".$this->MC."','".$id."', '{\"Popup1\":{\"point_ref\":\"$oldId\"}}', '".date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."')");
}
```

Comment: Здесь `union` вроде как и не нужен. Можно сделать `select`, с параметром `where id IN ($ids)` . А потом из этих данных сделать массовый инсерт

Comment: а как сделать массовый инсерт потом?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Так как, видимо, методы `ExecSQL_SelectOne` и подобные самописные, и мне неизвестна точная их работа, то попробую описать процесс в неком произвольно коде.

Есть соединение с БД `$db_conn`

Есть массив с идентификаторами `$ids = [2,3,666];`

Выбираем данные из базы, включающие айдишники:

```
$data = $db_conn->query('SELECT `field_one`, `field_two` 
    FROM `table_1` 
    WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $ids).')'
)->fetchAssoc;
```

Так, как с помощью `INSERT` можно вставить несколько строк, пример:

```
INSERT INTO example
VALUES
  (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
  (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
  (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
  (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');
```

, то далее формируем массив `values` для последующей вставки.

```
$values = [];
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $values[] = "('".$item['field_one']."','".($item['field_two'])."')";
}
```

и вставляем одним запросом:

```
$query ="INSERT INTO `table_2` (field_from_one, field_from_two)    
    VALUES".implode(", ", $values);

$db_conn -> simpleQuery($query);
```

Так как этот пример наглядный, то необходимо помнить и при этом учитывать, что стоит применять подготовленные запросы, плейсхолдеры и прочие методы для предотвращения `SQL` инъекций.

А также если данных очень много, то следует их разбить на несколько запросов вставки, т.к. имеются ограничения на количество вставляемых данных